Can't install apps
I Updated My App on Play-Store and My QA sended me this Issue when they are trying to update the app from Playstore.

What i have Done till Now:-

Checked Bundle.
Clear the local from Android Studio.
Checked on Google Dev site.
Try with my old Bundle.

Problem Description
When users try to update my app from the Google Play Store, they encounter an issue where the app cannot be installed. The error message is displayed in the screenshot:
"Can't install app - The package appears to be corrupt."

What I've Done So Far

Checked the App Bundle
Verified the .aab file generated by Android Studio.
Ensured all configurations are correct during the build process.



Cleared Local Builds:
*Cleaned and rebuilt the project using Android Studio:
Build > Clean Project
Build > Rebuild Project
Deleted the build folders and recompiled.
Checked on Google Play Console:
Verified the uploaded app bundle and release notes.
Ensured no issues were flagged during the upload process.
Tried With Old Bundles:
Rebuilt the app using a previously working bundle, but the issue persists.

Check the signature of the installed APK and the APK to be installed. Play Store sometimes tries to update app that have a different signature - of course this can only fail.

@Robert
If Signature is wrong, How can we make a Build for Playstore?
It will give the error at the time we are making the Signed build.

Usually Google maintains the signature key(s) for an app (Play App Signing). Therefore make sure you really have installed the old version from Play Store and not a locally built version which is signed by a different key.

I solved it, it seems the QA was having UAT Build and In store we had different.
